# if-else if ladder and Compiler Optimization

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Which of the below code will be more optimized for efficiency  **First function** or **Second function** in C/C++ gcc compiler ?

```
// First Function
if ( A && B && C ) {
    UpdateData();
} else if ( A && B ){
    ResetData();
}

//Second Function
if ( A && B) {
    if (C) {
        UpdateData();
    } else {
        ResetData();
    }
}
```

1. Do we get any performance improvement in **Second Function** ?
2. If **First Function** is used, can the compiler optimize it to **Second Method** on its own ?

Comment: You could look at the compiled code, but my bet would be they would compile into the exact same code. This also smells like micro-optimization, just write whatever is the most readable.

Comment: ...unless A or B involves an evaluation that might have side effects.

Comment: Why is this tagged C? C has no methods.

Comment: I bet you did not find this branching thing to be your bottleneck through profiling nor measured what switching between the two possibilities does.

Comment: `C/C++/gcc` – now that's a peculiar classification, conflating two programming languages and a compiler… by the way, why would you care? Does this particular piece of code cause a noticeable performance bottleneck in your application? If not, then just don't care.

Comment: I run both im my (hypothetical) computer and the first one performed better when run 2,653,456 times; the second one performed better when run 2,642,391 times. Note however that the difference was less than 0.000007362% per total run time!

Comment: You are effectively asking if the optimizing compiler can deduce whether converting `A` and `B` to bool expressions will have consistent results with no side-effects.  The answer is "Possibly."

Comment: @m0skit0: That "method" means "class member function" is a loose convention and by no means a requirement, contrary to your apparent believe that it concretely means a member function. There is no indication at all in this code that the OP is constraining his question example to _member_ functions. He is probably just misusing the term "method" instead of saying "function". Even if he weren't, what difference would it make to this question about conditionals? Therefore, the [tag:c] tag is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A large portion of this question will depend on what `A`, `B` and `C` really are (and the compiler will optimise it, as shown below). Simple types, definitely not worth worrying about. If they are some kind of "big number math" objects, or some complicated data type that needs 1000 instructions for each "is this `true` or not", then there will be a big difference if the compiler decides to make different code.

**As always when it comes to performance: Measure in your own code, use profiling to detect where the code spends MOST of the time, and then measure with changes to that code. Repeat until it runs fast enough [whatever that is] and/or your manager tells you to stop fiddling with the code. Typically, however, unless it's REALLY a high traffic area of the code, it will make little difference to re-arrange the conditions in an if-statement, it is the overall algorithm that makes most impact in the general case.**

If we assume A, B and C are simple types, such as `int`, we can write some code to investigate:

```
extern int A, B, C;
extern void UpdateData();
extern void ResetData();

void func1()
{
    if ( A && B && C ) {
        UpdateData();
    } else if ( A && B ){
        ResetData();
    }
}


void func2()
{
    if ( A && B) {
        if (C) {
            UpdateData();
        } else {
            ResetData();
        }
    }
}
```

gcc 4.8.2 given this, with -O1 produces this code:

```
_Z5func1v:
    cmpl    $0, A(%rip)
    je  .L6
    cmpl    $0, B(%rip)
    je  .L6
    subq    $8, %rsp
    cmpl    $0, C(%rip)
    je  .L3
    call    _Z10UpdateDatav
    jmp .L1
.L3:
    call    _Z9ResetDatav
.L1:
    addq    $8, %rsp
.L6:
    rep ret

_Z5func2v:
.LFB1:
    cmpl    $0, A(%rip)
    je  .L12
    cmpl    $0, B(%rip)
    je  .L12
    subq    $8, %rsp
    cmpl    $0, C(%rip)
    je  .L9
    call    _Z10UpdateDatav
    jmp .L7
.L9:
    call    _Z9ResetDatav
.L7:
    addq    $8, %rsp
.L12:
    rep ret
```

*In other words: No difference at all*

Using clang++ 3.7 (as of about 3 weeks ago) with -O1 gives this:

```
_Z5func1v:                              # @_Z5func1v
    cmpl    $0, A(%rip)
    setne   %cl
    cmpl    $0, B(%rip)
    setne   %al
    andb    %cl, %al
    movzbl  %al, %ecx
    cmpl    $1, %ecx
    jne .LBB0_2
    movl    C(%rip), %ecx
    testl   %ecx, %ecx
    je  .LBB0_2
    jmp _Z10UpdateDatav         # TAILCALL
.LBB0_2:                                # %if.else
    testb   %al, %al
    je  .LBB0_3
    jmp _Z9ResetDatav           # TAILCALL
.LBB0_3:                                # %if.end8
    retq

_Z5func2v:                              # @_Z5func2v
    cmpl    $0, A(%rip)
    je  .LBB1_4
    movl    B(%rip), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .LBB1_4
    cmpl    $0, C(%rip)
    je  .LBB1_3
    jmp _Z10UpdateDatav         # TAILCALL
.LBB1_4:                                # %if.end4
    retq
.LBB1_3:                                # %if.else
    jmp _Z9ResetDatav           # TAILCALL
.Ltmp1:
```

The chaining of and in the func1 of clang MAY be of benefit, but it's probably such a small difference that you should concentrate on what makes more sense from a logical perspective of the code.

**In summary: Not worth it**

Higher optimisation in g++ makes it do the same tailcall optimisation that clang does, otherwise no difference.

However, if we make `A`, `B` and `C` into external functions, which the compiler can't "understand", then we get a difference:

```
_Z5func1v:                              # @_Z5func1v
    pushq   %rax
.Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    callq   _Z1Av
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .LBB0_3

    callq   _Z1Bv
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .LBB0_3

    callq   _Z1Cv
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .LBB0_3

    popq    %rax
    jmp _Z10UpdateDatav         # TAILCALL
.LBB0_3:                                # %if.else
    callq   _Z1Av
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .LBB0_5

    callq   _Z1Bv
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .LBB0_5

    popq    %rax
    jmp _Z9ResetDatav           # TAILCALL
.LBB0_5:                                # %if.end12
    popq    %rax
    retq

_Z5func2v:                              # @_Z5func2v
    pushq   %rax
.Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    callq   _Z1Av
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .LBB1_4

    callq   _Z1Bv
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .LBB1_4

    callq   _Z1Cv
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .LBB1_3

    popq    %rax
    jmp _Z10UpdateDatav         # TAILCALL
.LBB1_4:                                # %if.end6
    popq    %rax
    retq
.LBB1_3:                                # %if.else
    popq    %rax
    jmp _Z9ResetDatav           # TAILCALL
```

Here we DO see the difference between `func1` and `func2`, where `func1` will call `A` and `B` twice - since the compiler can't assume that calling those functions ONCE will do the same thing as calling twice. [Consider that the functions `A` and `B` may be reading data from a file, calling `rand`, or whatever, the result of NOT calling that function may be that the program behaves differently.

(In this case I only posted clang code, but g++ produces code that has the same outcome, but slightly different ordering of the different lumps of code)