# c++ how to define constant function order that needs to be invoked for other developers

Tags: c++, function

The problem i have that i have several functions that needs to be invoked in defined order the order can't be breakable. 
now the code need to be continued and develop after i finish to code.
im looking for some method to set the functions in some kind of unbreakable structure.
for example i have:

```
function_1() { //do some stuff ..} ;  // must be first  
function_2() { //do some stuff based on function_1()..};  // must be second 
function_3() { //do some stuff based on function_1() and function_2()..};;  // must be third
```

they all under the main() app function .

Comment: Why not simply provide a 4th function that is meaant to be called via API, and move the other 3 into an unnamed namespace for instance?

Comment: Make `function123() { function1(); function2(); function3(); }`?

Comment: This is known as the **template pattern**.

Comment: Looking at your reputation, I guess that if you ask this, it's because there's a valid reason not to call all three together in a wrapper, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you have some solid reasons not to wrap all these three functions into one single function.

In this case the simplest approach, would be to manage a **status** that is shared between all the three functions:

```
static int function_status=0;    // shared status:  nothing was called 

function_1() { 
    if (status>0) 
       throw exception ("function_1 MUST be called first and only once");
    status=1;  // function_1 was called
    ...
}   
function_2() {
    if (status<1) 
       throw exception ("function_1 MUST be called before 2");
    else if (status>2) // I suppose function 2 could be called several times
       throw exception ("function_2 CANNOT be called after 3");
    status = 2;   
    ...
}
function_3() {
    if (status<2) 
       throw exception ("function_2 MUST be called before 3");
    else if (status==3) 
       throw exception ("function_3 CAN ONLY BE CALLED ONCE");
    status = 3; 
    ...
}
```

As you see, this status gives you the opportunity to check **very precisely** if the flow of execution respects the logic that you want.

Answer (score 3):

Create another function for public access, that guarantees the other three functions are called in the correct order. To prevent those functions are visible with the public API, you can hide them in an unnamed namespace.

In your header put

```
 bool function_4();
```

In your corresponding translation unit you create an unnamed namespace to prevent others from seeing those functions

```
 namespace {
     bool function_1() {
     }
     bool function_2() {
     }
     bool function_3() {
     }
 }
```

And define `function_4`

```
 bool  function_4() {
     return function_1() &&
            function_2() &&
            function_3();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a wrapping function

```
bool execute()
{
    return function_1() && function_2() && function_3();
}
```

The functions will be called in order, and it will short circuit if any of the functions fail. Assuming the functions return a `bool` indicating success/failure, if the function returns `true` all functions successfully completed, otherwise at least one of them failed.

Comment: This example shows bad approach to make predefined order of function execution. Compiler optimization can change order or even skip same functions in such logical expressions

Comment: @VolAnd The compiler would **absolutely not** change the order of this logical. The standard states that they must be called in exactly this order. And if the compiler skipped any functions, it would be the latter ones if an earlier one failed, which is "short circuiting behavior" which is **exactly what the OP wants**.

Comment: @Cyber Sorry, I have had to adopt your solution with my answer. I've been missing that "short circuiting behavior" point from OP's question. And of course you are right about it.

Comment: @Cyber : please explain, why you are so sure that any compiler with any optimization level in the expression `func_1() && func_2() && func_1() && func_3()` will call `func_1()` twice?

Comment: @VolAnd: Because the C++ spec says so. At least if `func_1()` isn't available for inspection by the compiler to determine that it has no side-effects. See for example the second example in my answerhere:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517041/if-else-if-ladder-and-compiler-optimization/28518085#28518085 - the compiler is not sure if `A()` and `B()` has no side-effects, so generates code to call them twice. However, if you do `func(func1(), func2(), func1())`, there is no guarantee which order the two calls to `func1` and the call to `func2` are made.

Comment: @Mats && Cyber : What exactly C++ standards said about calling functions in logical expressions? And would functions func_2 and func_3 be called after func_1 returns false? (refer to my example with `(func_1() && func_2() && func_1() && func_3() )` )

Comment: @VolAnd [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order). There is a forced sequence point after the first expression. Therefore, even with "as-if" optimization, the compiler CANNOT change the order of evaluation in this logical. And no, once `func_1` returned false, nothing after that would execute after that, hence the "short-circuiting" behavior.

Comment: The standard guarantees that `func_2` and `func_1` and `func_3` are NOT called after the first call to `func_1` is made. I'm not going to quote the standard in a comment, but the standard guarantees that function calls are made if they have side effects, and it also guarantees short circuiting of logical and/or expressions, so if you do `if(ptr && ptr->x > 0) ...` it is guaranteed to NOT access `ptr->x` if `ptr` is 0.

Comment: "Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated."

Comment: @VolAnd The order is specified in **5.14 Logical AND operator**.

Comment: Thanks for clarification of Cyber's idea. user63898 must make his functions bool

Answer (score 2):

One hack you can try is to have `function_1()` return a type that only it can construct and then use this as a parameter to `function_2()`

```
class created_by_function_1 {
   created_by_function_1() { /* private constructor */ }
   friend created_by_function_1 function_1();
 };

created_by_function_1 function_1() { 
  // do stuff
  return created_by_function_1();
}

void function_2(created_by_function_1) {
}
```

Now you can only use `function_2` if you first called `function_1`.

```
auto proof = function_1();
function_2(proof); // OK

function_2(created_by_function_1()); // Compilation error
```

I would advise against using this :)

Comment: If you go one step further, you'll end up with a *fluent api style* 'myContext.function1().function2().function3()'

Comment: @tofi9 I assume the OP wants to have other stuff between invocations of his functions, otherwise why expose them separately (this is why I think he's not using the template method pattern)

Comment: There is one catch: nothing forces the client code to call all the functions.

Answer (score 2):

The simple case of ordering functions is to make a single function that is called by the user, that does all three of the subfunctions. However, this doesn't always work. The user may need to do some processing after `function1` before calling `function2`. In that case, you need some kind of extra context, e.g.

```
class Context
{
   friend Function1, Function2, Function3;
   enum State 
   {
     f0, f1, f2, f3 
   } state;
public:
   Context() { state = f0; }
   ~Context() { if (state != f3) { ... may need to do stuff... }
}

void Function1(Context &ctxt)
{
   assert(ctxt.state == f0);
   ctxt.state = f1;
   ... 
}


void Function2(Context &ctxt)
{
   assert(ctxt.state == f1);
   ctxt.state = f2;
   ... 
}

void Function3(Context &ctxt)
{
   assert(ctxt.state == f2);
   ctxt.state = f3;
   ... 
}

int main()
{
   Context c;

   Function1(c);
   ...
   Function2(c);
   ...
   Function3(c);
   // c will be destroyed and check that state is f3.
}
```

Comment: see @Christophe answer the same but more simple